# What does "service group" mean in the context of Azure Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I could not find information on the **service group** concept. But it's needed for Service Fabric resource monitoring and for service autoscaling.

Comment: How did you come to the notion of a *service group*?

Comment: this might help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58973e2b-01a4-4c9a-baa2-34f7126f9ab4/service-group-usage?forum=AzureServiceFabric

Comment: @PeterBons I searched **LoadMetrics** under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-service-model-schema-elements . And correlated **LoadMetrics** with **ServiceGroup**. And I have never met this concept before with Service Fabric.